# how to enable safari exit prompt in version 9.0.2

Tags: safari

I keep accidentally closing my Safari browser on my OS X Yosemite, Safari version 9.0.2 and loose all of my open web pages I am working from.  How do I enable a prompt to ask me if I am sure I want to exit Safari 9.0.2 so I do not accidentally close safari and loose all my open screens?